# Cannot retrieve image from Firebase into TableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I just began to learn Firebase a week ago, but right now I am facing a problem of not able to load image from Firebase to my TableViewCell. I can retrieve data such as text information and the URL of the image from Firebase Realtime Database but not able to make use of those URL in order to fire up image on the TableViewCell. May you all help me identify the problems? I can retrieve everything such as text information as well as the image URL but how can I make the image pop up on the cell? All your help would be highly appreciate!

**This is the ViewController that responsible to display the TableViewCell**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseStorage


class NewsFeedViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    var rubthort:String = ""
    var linkRub:String?

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrItem.count

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "mycell", for: indexPath) as! NewsFeed
        // textlabel
        // detailtextlabel
        cell.textLabel?.text = arrItem[indexPath.row].name
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = arrItem[indexPath.row].price
        //cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "flower")
        // Get image
        let id = RetrieveData()

        if let imageLink = self.linkRub {
            let url = URL(string: imageLink)
            //let data = NSData(contentsOf: url!)
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
                    // download hit an error so return out
                    if error != nil {
                        print(error)
                        return
                    }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(data: data!)

                }

            }.resume()
        }

        return cell

    }

    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    // Array of PlasticItem
    var arrItem = [RetrieveData]()

    @IBOutlet weak var tblView: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        retrieveData()

    } // Ends of viewDidLoad

    func retrieveData() {
        // Getting a node from database
        let retRef = ref.child("item/electronic")
        // Observing data changes
        retRef.observe(DataEventType.value) { (dataSnapshot) in
            // Remove array item everytime there is a new reference to the data in Firebase
            self.arrItem.removeAll()
            // Check if there are any children or second object inside the parent object
            if dataSnapshot.childrenCount > 0 {
              // Loop over all children's object
              for post in dataSnapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                    let object = post.value as! [String: Any]
                    let getName = object["name"] as! String
                    let getPrice = object["price"] as! String
                    let getImage = object["itemURL"] as! String
                    print(getName)
                    print(getPrice)
                    print(getImage)
                self.linkRub = getImage
                self.arrItem.append(RetrieveData(cat: "", name: getName, price: getPrice, rub: getImage))

                }
               self.tblView.reloadData()
            }// Ends of if statement
            else if dataSnapshot.childrenCount == 0{
                print("No Data Found")
            }
        } // Ends of retRef.observe
    } // Ends of retrieveData()
    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */
}
```

**This is the model struct**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

struct RetrieveData{
    var cat: String
    var name: String
    var price: String
    var rub: String?

    init(){
        self.cat = ""
        self.name = ""
        self.price = ""
        self.rub = ""

    }
    init(cat:String, name:String, price:String, rub: String){
        self.cat = cat
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
        self.rub = rub
    }

}
```

Comment: as your code, any cell shoud receive the same image?

Comment: @HồngPhúc Hi, no it should receive different images based on the URL.

Comment: as i can see, self.linkRub assigned by "getImage", out of for loop, it just have one value. and u using it to receive image

Comment: "imageLink" should equa arrItem[indexPath.row].rub